# Analysing significance in grouped variables

Tags: hypothesis-testing, anova, group-differences

I have imputed a dataset which has 20 observations.
Participants were asked to rate the importance of 13 variables under a certain circumstance, from 0 to 25.

I imputed this using `mice(imp=25, max_it=25)`, and got a nice dataset after a few hours.
I'm now analysing it using boxplots per circumstance (thus 13 boxplots at a time), but wonder how I can measure the significance per circumstance of boxplots. [image: Groups of boxplots]

In the above example it is clear that the circumstance `Revenue: 0 to 2 Million` is different from the `Revenue: 10 to 50 Million` and possibly from `2 to 10 Million` but how can I measure this statistically?

My data has a normal distribution. A friend recommended ANOVA, but that's univariate and I feel that 20 observations is too little...

I saw: [How to compare two groups on a measure of social skills that includes 5 subscales where each subscale is number correct out of 12?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/30512/how-to-compare-two-groups-on-a-measure-of-social-skills-that-includes-5-subscale?rq=1) but not really sure if that applies since its non-parametric.

Comment: If the scale of the responses runs from 0 to 25 then the suggestion that your data has a normal distribution will be false. Where the data runs up against each bound the discrepancy from normality might become severe.

Comment: I think that you should explore some different data visualisation approaches before worrying about hypothesis testing. Perhaps a dithered dot plot would make the data easier to see.

Comment: I disagree, the boxplots clearly show min, max, median, mean, and more or less the distribution. Enough data for understanding what the 20 participants entered and agreed upon

Comment: perhaps a correlation would work?

Comment: How did you test whther your data is normally distributed? When I look at your plot, I wouldn't be surprised that some of your variables are not normally distributed.

Comment: Wilk-Shapiro test, in R, over each individual variable. But there's an error in the plot above :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you asked 20 participants to give a score for 13 variables in 3 different conditions. Which means you have a within subjects design. I suggest the following steps:

1) Test for normality. You can do this both visually and statistically. Visually: make a barplot/histogram for each variable in each condition. This will give you 39 plots (or 13 faceted plots for each variable). Statistically: do a Shapiro test for each variable in each condition. You should do both in my opinion.

2) Statistical testing for differences. The type of test you use depends on the normality of your data. If everything is normally distributed, you can use a repeated measures ANOVA (you can do this with the [`ez` package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ez/index.html) in R). As a post-hoc test you can use pairwise t-tests.

When your data is not normally distributed, you can use a robust repeated measures ANOVA. You'll need the [`WRS` package](https://r-forge.r-project.org/projects/wrs/) for that.

---

When you want to reduce the impact of outliers, you have several options:

1. Remove the outliers. Not preferred. Only when you have reason to
   believe that the case does not belong to the intended population.
2. Transform the data. As outliers tend to skew the distribution, a
   transformation can reduce this influence. The most common types of
   transformations are: log, square-root & reciprocal (1/x).
3. Replacing the value. Only use when transformation fails. There are several options: (a)
   next highest(lowest) score plus(minus) one, (b) converting back from a z-score, (c) mean plus standard deviation.

Source: [Discovering statistics with R (Andy Field)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1446200469)

Comment: Tested for normality, using Wilk-Shapiro test, and all vars are Normal distributed.
Can I do an ANOVA over 20 observation? Isn't that too little? Also, looking at the broad sistribution, is the mean too much pushed around due to outliers at 20 observations?

Comment: For a normal ANOVA, 20 participants is not enough. For a repeated measures ANOVA with three repeated measures, 20 participant is acceptable (actually you have 20*3=60 observations). However, working with e.g. 30 participants will increase the reliability.

Comment: Do you have many outliers?

Comment: in general not, 0-2 per condition (thus 13 vars). Some conditions have up to 20. In the image above, there are 3 outliers (little dots in the 3rd condition)

Comment: As the outliers occur in seperate variables with only one per variable (in the image), the mean is probably not affected to much. In a condition with 20 outliers, it depends on how they are distributed. Are they concentrated in specific variables? If so, are these varables still normally distributed?

Comment: no, the max I've seen is 4 in 1 var. But there tends to be a large difference between de median/mean/mode. And in this research the mode is more important than the mean of the answers

Comment: When there is a large difference between median/mean/mode, are those variables still normally distributed? Are those variables skewed? I'll update my answer with some info on dealing with outliers.

Comment: Can I use the Robust Repeated Measures ANOVA from the `WRS` package also on parametric data?

Comment: Technically, you can do that. but why would you? When you have parametric data, use a parametric test.

Comment: Interesting that Field omits the options that would for me come right at the top: - use a more suitable distributional model (so the outliers are not outliers), or - use a methodology that's quite robust to outliers.

Answer (score 0):

Does a Kruskal-Wallis one-way analysis of variance test work? It is non-parametric and uses ranking to test significance in differences between samples. It is the non-parametric equivalent to ANOVA. It might not work on all of the variables at once?

http://udel.edu/~mcdonald/statkruskalwallis.html

But I also think data visualization is the best idea. It looks like you have a ton of data plotted in a very traditional but limited way (box plots). I also like the idea of subsetting the variables and analyzing individual variables or groups of variables at a time.

PS [Welch's ANOVA](http://udel.edu/~mcdonald/statanovasig.html#welch) accounts for high heteroscedasticity.

Comment: A Kruskal-Wallis test can only be used when you have independant groups, which is not the case in this example.

Comment: Oopps! You are absolutely right. I jumped to Kruskal-Wallis due to the problems using ANOVA in this case. I had a similar issue with an experiment I performed last year and saw parallels here. My mistake!